# TFS functional tests run only when user is logged in to test box

Tags: wpf, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to integrate WPF application functional tests into TFS CI and this works only partly.

In TFS Build Definitions there are steps `Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment` and `Run Functional Tests`. The agent is configured to run as interactive process. Everything works only when someone is logged into the testing server and actually sees the screen. Once you log out from the server, then CI gets stuck on the task `ConfigureTestAgent` of `Deploy TestAgent` step (see logs below).

The agent runs under same credentials as used to RDP to the testing box. What exactly is failing there - communication to TFS server or something else?

Functional tests get stuck with the following console log:

```
Starting task: Deploy TestAgent on dpp02

******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: c:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\DeployTestAgent.ps1
DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
DistributedTests: Inputs provided are:
DistributedTests: Username: ts\aak
DistributedTests: Use HTTP Port: True
DistributedTests: Run as process: True
DistributedTests: Login Automatically: True
DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True
DistributedTests: Agent would be downloaded from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
DistributedTests: Update test agent: True
DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent on remote machine: C:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\TestAgentInstall.ps1
DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote machine: C:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
DistributedTests: Path to script that downloads test agent on azure remote machines : C:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\DownloadTestAgent.ps1
DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is installed on remote machine: C:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1
DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is already running on remote machine: C:\Agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.25\VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse.ps1
DistributedTests: Task 'VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is being run
DistributedTests: Task 'VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse' on machine 'dpp02:5985' completed.
DistributedTests: Starting to download testagent
DistributedTests: testagent is downloaded at: C:\Users\aak\AppData\Local\Temp\34b091f9-093d-46cd-8635-3a1164d777fe
DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is being run
DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' completed.
DistributedTests: Task 'DeployTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is being run
DistributedTests: Task 'DeployTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' completed.
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is being run
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'dpp02:5985' is taking time. Please Wait
```

DTAExecutionHost.exe.log has this:

```
V, 7096, 16, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.016, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener:DispatchAsync
I, 7096, 16, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.017, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, ExecutionTaskStateModel.ListenerCommandReceived : Requesting a stop on Stop command.
I, 7096, 16, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.017, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : Stop listening on Stop command.
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.017, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, ExecutionTaskStateModel.RunStateTransitionsAsync : The task was cancelled
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting RegisteredAgentIdOnTfs on agent machine
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting RegisteredAgentIdOnTfs on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting RegisteredAgentIdOnTfs on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting RegisteredAgentIdOnTfs on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting RegisteredAgentIdOnTfs on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting TfsUrl on agent machine
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.022, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting TfsUrl on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting TfsUrl on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting TfsUrl on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting TfsUrl on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlEnvUrl on agent machine
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlEnvUrl on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting DtlEnvUrl on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlEnvUrl on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting DtlEnvUrl on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlMachineName on agent machine
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlMachineName on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.023, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting DtlMachineName on agent machine - 32 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.024, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removing agent setting DtlMachineName on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.024, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, Removed agent setting DtlMachineName on agent machine - 64 bit hive
I, 7096, 6, 2017/08/09, 17:52:52.024, DPP02\DTAExecutionHost, ExecutionHost.UnregisterFromServer : Agent is unregistering from server.
Web method running: [http://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects/_apis/test/Agents/33] (DELETE)33[test]
Web method response: [http://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects/_apis/test/Agents/33] (DELETE)33[test] 43 ms
I, 312, 1, 2017/08/09, 17:55:23.897, 24814877456, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 312, 1, 2017/08/09, 17:55:23.916, 24814914498, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Servicehttp://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects
W, 312, 1, 2017/08/09, 17:55:23.998, 24815107475, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Service task failed. Retry attempt 10.
I, 2324, 1, 2017/08/09, 17:59:39.692, 467469870, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 2324, 1, 2017/08/09, 17:59:39.723, 467537817, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Servicehttp://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects
I, 3240, 1, 2017/08/09, 18:02:03.753, 382139782, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 3240, 1, 2017/08/09, 18:02:03.769, 382166680, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Servicehttp://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects
I, 1288, 1, 2017/08/09, 18:06:12.974, 462638694, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 1288, 1, 2017/08/09, 18:06:12.990, 462666317, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Servicehttp://tfs01:8080/tfs/XRX%20Projects
I, 3908, 1, 2017/08/09, 18:08:09.827, 238326434, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue usually happens when the group policy on the machine resets the Autologon registry key required for test execution, while the deploy test agent step tries to set this registry key.

For Test agent to run interactively, we need to have a valid user session on the box and if that session is not present then via autologon to create that session.

So, please check if you have enabled the autologon for your test machine, or any group policies restrict the autologon.

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

1. If you have successfully performed the test before, just try to
   reboot the test machine and uncheck ‘**Update Test Agent**’ under
   “**Advanced**” (by default it’s selected and forces to reinstall TA
   everytime).
2. If not performed before, you could try to download the test agent
   2015, then install it on that machine manually and check the result.

If that doesn't work, then try:

- Configure as service and use if that is an option.
- Ask your IT admin to disable your domain policies around autologon
  for your test machines.

On the other hand, you may try to find another test machine to test if test agents can be deployed well on it.

Comment: Thank you. Disabling GPO's fixed the issue